# HighlightedTextColor changes the text color of UILabel when tableviewcell selected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uilabel

There are many examples to change the color of `UILabel` text when `UITableViewCell` selected. But all examples explained with following lines

```
if cell.selected {
  cell.txtLabel1.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}else {
  cell.txtLabel1.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

But setting **cell.txtLabel1.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.redColor()** is very easy. Will bolded line cause any problem and why other examples are not having the bolded line implementation?

Without setting isHighlighted to UILabel also changes the color of the text when the UITableViewCell is selected. Code is pasted below for reference

```
class MenuViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle:UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var imgIcon:UIImageView?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        let selectedView = UIView()
        selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 244.0/255.0, green: 244.0/255.0, blue: 245.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
        lblTitle?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 224.0/255.0, green: 121.0/255.0, blue: 43.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Will bolded line cause any problem.

I do not see any problem using this property on `UILabel`, if you read the docs of this property it states:

> This color is applied to the label automatically whenever the isHighlighted property is set to true.

[more info here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620540-highlightedtextcolor)

Its is the matter of what works best, but off course the usage would differ, like so:

```
UILabel.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.red
```

Toggle `isHighlighted`

```
UILabel.isHighlighted = cell.isSelected
```

**Update**

To change `UILabel.isHighlighted` automatically when you set `cell.isSelected`, you can subclass `UITableViewCell`, like so:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var label = UILabel!

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            label.isHighlighted = isSelected
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you meant say that UILabel should be set to Highlighted when UITableViewCell selected.

Comment: Yes, it indicates whether the label should be drawn with a highlight. Both Enabled and Highlighted control the appearance of the label, representing the isEnabled and isHighlighted properties, respectively. When Enabled is unchecked, the text is drawn dimmed to indicate that it is inactive. When Highlighted is checked, the text is rendered in the Highlighted color. more info https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel

Comment: My code works without following code,  override var isSeleted : Bool { didSet { label.isHighlighted = isSelected } } } for reference I have updated my question with my code.